# Internet connection lost during the upgrade to 18.04

Tags: networking, upgrade

So i was upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 via terminal, when my family member decided it would be an amazing idea to turn off the Wi-Fi and setup a password for it.

After he'd done that, i wasnt able to connect to the Wi-Fi, even though i knew the password (because it was over 8 characters long, and thats a problem for some reason), which lasted for about an hour, after which the 18.04 was installed.

During that time i've seen some attempts to download something running through the terminal, which failed, because the connection wasnt there.

The system works fine (i dont see any problems apart from audio files not playing in the browser, but thats a normal ubuntu behavior for me at this point) but i was wondering, if there's a way to check what failed to download, and to download it all now.

I hope im clear, im pretty new to all this.

Comment: My question is How to check if everything that was supposed to be installed, actually did install (during the upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04).

 I did absolutely zero research. Wi-Fi question is not a question that needs answering, Im sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: Please tell me on what to elaborate, i really am not understanding what info you need. I upgraded from 16 to 18.during the upgrade  my internet connection was lost, and several packages didnt download. So thats why im asking, is there a command, or some app, that lets me check the integrity of the currently installed distribution? How can i be more specific? There either is such app, or command, or there is not. Please tell me what additional info do you exactly need to answer such a question, because thats all i can think of at the moment.

Comment: Thats why i asked if there was a  very specific integrity checking method. Didn't ask for a "God" command.

I have no idea which packages didn't download, also i don't know how to figure that out after the fact (the terminal is long since closed), because if i knew that, i wouldn't ask this question.
I didn't encounter any errors only messages that a package cant be downloaded because i have no internet connection (are those errors?).

I've already told, that i upgraded via terminal, is that the method info you need?

Software manager says i'm up to date. So im good?

Comment: Please consider this question answered. Thank you for your time.